# Problems with Emotion (Styled Components) on Gatsby

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components, emotion

I use Emotion to make styled components on my projects and now it is giving me problems. I install it like this:

```
npm i @emotion/react @emotion/styled gatsby-plugin-emotion
```

And, for example, if I want to use it in the Header component I do this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';
import Navegacion from './navegacion';
import { jsx, css } from '@emotion/react';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header
      css={css`
        background-color: #0d283b;
        padding: 1rem;
      `}
    >
      <div
        css={css`
          max-width: 120rem;
          margin: 0 auto;
          text-align: center;
          @media (min-width: 768px) {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
          }
        `}
      >
        <Link>Bienes Raíces</Link>
        <Navegacion />
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}
 
export default Header;
```

But when I run gatsby develop, It give me this error

```
`WebpackError: The `@emotion/core` package has been renamed to `@emotion/react`. Please import it like this `import { jsx } from '@emotion/react'.
```

Someone can help me?

My package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.1.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.0.0",
    "gatsby": "^2.26.1",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.5.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-emotion": "^4.5.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.6.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.4.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.8.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.5.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.6.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0"
  },
```

and my gatsby-config file:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-emotion`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    // {
    //   resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
    //   options: {
    //     name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
    //     short_name: `starter`,
    //     start_url: `/`,
    //     background_color: `#663399`,
    //     theme_color: `#663399`,
    //     display: `minimal-ui`,
    //     icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
    //   },
    // },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because in Emotion 11 the package names have changed. I don't believe `gatsby-plugin-emotion` is up to date yet, so that error is probably coming from the plugin code.

If you would prefer to use the code you have already written, follow [the v10 Emotion docs](https://5faaafd0bd0f3f0008469537--emotion.netlify.app/docs/introduction) and set the dependency version for @emotion/core to "~10.0.0" in your `package.lock` file.

You don't need @emotion/react in v10. You don't need @emotion/styled unless you want to use Styled Components (e.g. `` const Foo = styled("div")`font-size: 14px;`; ``).

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `@emotion/core` and run `npm install` again. Then in your component just use the syntax as exactly they are in your code, or use something like:

```
import { css, jsx } from '@emotion/react'

const color = 'white'

render(
  <div
    css={css`
      padding: 32px;
      background-color: hotpink;
      font-size: 24px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      &:hover {
        color: ${color};
      }
    `}
  >
    Hover to change color.
  </div>
)
```